# How to write a python program for the Fibonacci series and need to show series in Pyramid?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I want to write a Program for the Fibonacci series and need to show series in Pyramid.
Enter (through command line) the number of times the Fibonacci has to iterate.
Ex:
Enter the number of times
6
Fibonacci Series of the number is: 0 1 1 2 3

Below is the expected output -

```
0
0 1
0 1 1
0 1 1 2
0 1 1 2 3
0 1 1 2 3 5
```

I have tried this code as below -

```
n= int(input("enter the number of rows: "))
a=0
b=1

for i in range(a,n):
    a=0
    b=1
    print(b,end="")
    for j in range(a,i-1):
        c=a+b
        print(c,end="")
        a=b
        b=c
    print()
```

But this is giving below output

```
1
1
11
112
1123
11235
```

the above output starting from "1" but the expected output should start from "0"

Please help me with correct python code as expected
Thanks

Comment: Remove `end` param

Comment: it should only be `print (c)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is some small change that your code will require. You have to make end=" ", so that it will print space there.

```
n= int(input("enter the number of rows: "))
a=0
b=1

for i in range(a,n):
    a=0
    b=1
    print(a, b,end=" ")
    for j in range(a,i-1):
        c=a+b
        print(c,end=" ")
        a=b
        b=c
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I am asking another this here. my Fibonacci is starting from 1 but the expected triangle should start from 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
n = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))

fib = []
for i in range(n):
    fib.append(fib[-2] + fib[-1] if i > 1 else i)
    print(' '.join(str(x) for x in fib))
```

Output:

```
0
0 1
0 1 1
0 1 1 2
0 1 1 2 3
0 1 1 2 3 5
```

In your code, you are computing the Fibonacci sequence from zero again and again for each row, which is redundant. Instead, you can make a list and add one item at each iteration.

I've used `join` to insert a blank between entries, which I believe is more "pythonic."

Answer (score 2):

It often makes for simpler code if you separate computation from doing pretty output. So construct your series first:

```
>>> series = [0,1]
>>> n = 6
>>> while len(series) < n:
        series.append(series[-1]+series[-2])
>>> series
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Then do the output:

```
>>> sseries = [str(s) for s in series]
>>> sseries
['0', '1', '1', '2', '3', '5']

>>> for row in range(len(sseries)+1):
        print (" ".join(sseries[:row])) 
0
0 1
0 1 1
0 1 1 2
0 1 1 2 3
0 1 1 2 3 5
```